# Copy directories while excluding or isolating certain extensions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I often find myself wanting to copy directories around with either:

1. having to copy **only** specific extensions, or
2. having to **exclude** specific extensions.

For this task, I wrote some Python which I am calling from the `cmd`.

The Python script is *humbly* called `copy_master.py` and I have also set an environment variable for it called `%Pcopy%`.

> copy_master.py

```
def classify(dirs):
    return {(1, 0): dirs, (0, 1): dirs[::-1], (0, 0): [None, None], (1, 1): [1, 1]}[tuple(map(os.path.isdir, dirs))]


def include(d, files):
    return [f for f in files if not any(f.endswith('.' + x) for x in sys.argv[4].split(',')) and not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(d, f))]


def refuse(d, files):
    return [f for f in files if any(f.endswith('.' + x) for x in sys.argv[4].split(',')) and not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(d, f))]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import shutil
    import os
    import sys

    if len(sys.argv) < 3 or sys.argv[1].lower() == 'help':
        print('\nParameters:: \n\t > Source and Destination directories: order does not matter; one of the specified '
              'directories MUST NOT exist and this is taken to be the destination. \n\t > Mode: (+) for copying specific'
              ' file extensions only OR (-) for skipping specific extensions. \n\t > Extensions: comma delimited list of'
              ' file extensions to be copied or ignored.\n\nExample Usage:\n\t{0:} {1:} + bdf  -> Copies only bdf files '
              'from {1:} to {0:}\n\t{0:} {1:} - f06,xdb  -> Copies everything but f06 & xbd files from {1:} to {0:}'.format(r'I:\do\not\exist', r'I:\have\the\files\you\want'))
    elif len(sys.argv) > 2:
        src, dst = classify(sys.argv[1:3])
        if src is None:
            raise IOError('The source directory should exist!')
        elif src == 1:
            raise IOError('The destination directory should not exist!')

        if len(sys.argv) == 5:
            mode = sys.argv[3]
            print('\rCopying...', end='')
            shutil.copytree(src, dst, ignore={'+': include, '-': refuse}[mode])
            print('\rCopying completed')
        else:
            q = input('Extensions and execution mode have not been specified. Everything is going to be copied! Proceed (Y/N)?\n::')
            if q.lower() in ['n', 'no']:
                exit()
            else:
                print('Copying...')
                shutil.copytree(src, dst)
```

---

Example usages (with the command prompt open, type):

- copy **only** specific extension:

  ```
  %Pcopy% I:\do\not\exist I:\have\the\files\you\want + txt
  #                                                  ^
  ```
- **exclude** specific extensions from the copying:

  ```
  %Pcopy% I:\do\not\exist I:\have\the\files\you\want - xlsx,bat
  #                                                  ^
  ```

There are a couple of things I am not so happy\sure about:

1. Have I sacrificed too much readability in the `classify()` function? Are `dict`s meant to be (*ab*)used like that? What should I be returning in the `(1, 1)` case (if both directories exist)?
2. Is the use of global `sys.argv` in `include()` and `refuse()` ok?
3. How can I handle the different ways a user might use the script in the best possible way? Not quite happy about the `if` statements in the `__main__`.

Apart from the points discussed above, feel free to suggest other changes or even an entirely different approach. And by all means, use the script if you like it ;)

**Bonus Points**:
Currently, directories that have to be quoted to be recognized by the `cmd` are not handled (e.g., `C:\users\Example\This&That`, note the `&`)

Comment: Not 100% sure it fits, but have you considered the [`glob` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) with the "glob" patterns to match files and directories?

Comment: @alecxe I know about it but somehow did not consider it for the  `include()` and `refuse()`. Will look into it.

Answer (score 5):

> Is the use of global `sys.argv` in `include()` and `refuse()` ok?

- At the moment it's not really readable, since `sys.argv[4]` doesn't say much... This could be solved by using `argparse` or naming your `sys.argv` to variables

> How can I handle the different ways a user might use the script in the best possible way? Not quite happy about the if statements in the `__main__`.

- Use [argeparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) that will relieve the clutter from the `if __name__ == '__main__'` and make it easier to add optional parameters in your script.

  ```
  def parse_arguments():
      """Arguments parser."""

      parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage='%(prog)s [optional] <source> <destination>',
                                   description='Copy master',
                                   formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
                                   epilog='''<your help string>''')

      # Next you can add arguments like this...
      parser.add_argument('source', type=str, help='source directory')
      parser.add_argument('destination', type=str, help='destination directory')
      parser.add_argument('-t', '--types', type=str, help='included types')
      ...

      # Parse the arguments to the object
      args = parser.parse_args()

      # Check if all args are set or something
      if not args.types:
          parser.error('No typyes are specified')
      return args

  # Now you can call this from the main
  if __name__ == '__main__':
      import argparse
      args = parse_arguments()
      # And call your arguments like...
      # args.source, etc...
  ```

---

## Bonus

- **imports should be at the top of the file!**

  At the moment when this script is imported to another module, it will not import all dependencies.

  *Note that you can import `argparse` in `__main__`, since this will on be executed from the cli*
- **(Subjective style)** You might consider to chop lines for better readability

  > ```
  > return [f for f in files if any(f.endswith('.' + x) for x in sys.argv[4].split(',')) and not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(d, f))]
  > ```

  Could be this:

  ```
  return [file
          for file in files if any(file.endswith('.' + x)
          for x in sys.argv[4].split(','))
          and not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(d, f))]
  ```
- At your help string consider using a heredoc string

  `"""Heredoc string"""` Or consider setting it as the docstring `__doc__ = """Help"""`